# How to investigate reponseText/long text in Firefox 57.x console?

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging, firefox, console.log

When I inspect an AJAX response in the Firefox 57.0.4 console on Ubuntu 17.10 I see

[image]

and am wondering how to inspect `responseText` since there's apparently no function to expand the text and I assume there's more because otherwise the XML response wouldn't be valid and an error be displayed in the console.

Comment: Just `console.log(yourError.responseText)` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the network tab and then look at response tab.

[image]